# Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 94 Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102

Tags: google-chrome, version

I got this error messege when I do selenium.
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 94
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

So I tried to install Chrome version 94. However, even in the ver 94, there are three kinds of ver94. Which ver94 should I install?

ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.113
ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61
ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.41

Comment: update your chrome driver to latest  version or 98.other wise you will get the exception

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=98.0.4758.102/

Comment: So, current my chrome browser version is 94 and I have to update to version 98?

Comment: yes update both to latest

Comment: I downloaded 98 version and put this in the same directory with ipynb notebook. When I enter this code, `driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver_98.exe')` ,
I still get the same error messege. 
What can I do ...? :(

Answer (score 1):

[image]

here chrome construct `path` parameter represent chrome driver path

```
webdriver.Chrome("E:\idm\compressed\chromedriver.exe")
```

**Install selenium package**

```
pip install selenium
```

**Selenium code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


    driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\idm\compressed\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
    assert "Python" in driver.title
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("pycon")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
    # driver.close()
```